# change Text under TabBarIcon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `UITabBarController` with 5 views. 
When I click on the tab bar in a ViewController, I have set up in the Attributes Inspector an Identifier like "**Featured**" because I want the Icon of "**Featured**" to be in the Tab Bar. But I want only the Icon of "Featured" and not the text "Featured" under it, but when I try to change this in the Attributes Inspector, the Identifier changes to custom and the icon is gone. My question is: How can I change the text but also use the icon or do I have to make it custom and make the icon myself?

Comment: The title " item " right , in storyboard you can remove this.

Comment: You will have to use custom image for this.